# Do people typically go through 'stages' when experiencing remorse, similar to grief?

Tags: emotion, well-being

It's well known, at least in pop psychology, that grief comes in a number of stages.

Whether that's [accurate or not](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20130219-are-there-five-stages-of-grief), I'm interested in finding out if there's a similar phenomenon with remorse?

Comment: Those who are grieving could also have some remorse involved for things they may or may not have done, so the stages of grief can be involved there; although this would be part of the grieving process.  With remorse on its own?.... I'm not completely convinced but it will be interesting to see what comes out of this. I will have to do some digging on this myself. Good question